# How to use multiple filter in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

i want to filetr my csv file using multiple value. For example

```
   NEID  VPNID  DSCP  COS
0  2645      1    18    1
1  2645      1    48    6
2  2645      2    34    2
3  2645      2    46    6
4  2645      3    46    6
```

I want to filter row whose value in DSCP column must match 18 and 48 (user defined)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv ("C:\Users\mnarwal\.PyCharmCE2019.1\config\scratches\VIL.csv")
print(df.head())
print(df.columns)
print(df.shape)
dscp1 = raw_input("DSCP1 Value = ")
dscp2 = raw_input("DSCP2 Value = ")
print(df.query([(df['DSCP'] == dscp1) & (df['DSCP'] == dscp2)]))
```

But above code is not running as per expectations as giving below error

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py:1649: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  result = method(y)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mnarwal/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(df.query([(df['DSCP'] == dscp1) & (df['DSCP'] == dscp2)]))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3085, in query
    raise ValueError(msg.format(type(expr)))
ValueError: expr must be a string to be evaluated, <type 'list'> given

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `query` to acquire that slice:

```py
print(df[(df['DSCP'] == dscp1) & (df['DSCP'] == dscp2)])
```

It is worth pointing out, though, that the slicing used above will never return anything - it is impossible to have two different values in the same row for `DSCP` column.

If you wanted to use query method, you would have to provide a query string, rather than using series slicing syntax.

Query method equivalent would look roughly like this:

`print(df.query(f'DSCP == {dscp1} & DCP == {dscp2}'))`

Read up more on querying [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html).

Comment: good one. +1 , i believe OP has another prob: the qury should not be an and condition, instead `print(df.query(f'DSCP == {dscp1} | DSCP == {dscp2}'))` here

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, this will work.

```
def filter_my_df(x, y):
    return df[(df['DSCP'] == x) | (df['DSCP'] == y)]
new_df = filter_my_df(18, 48)
```

I don't think "&" will work because the value cannot be 18 and 48 at the same time. That's why I used "|" instead.

Regards